# How to set data in three column per row in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have a problem with displaying data in my table. I have 5 rows data in my deal_coupons' table and I show all the data with using table. I want to display data in three column per row, but I get all data in one row.

```
<table border="1" class="table datatable table-striped table-bordered" style="" width="100%"> 
     <tbody>
            <tr>
                @foreach($dealCoupons as $dealCoupon)
                   <td>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}"> 
                       <strong>{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}</strong>
                   </td>
                @endforeach
           </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public function editDealCoupon($id)
{
    $deal = Deal::findOrFail($id);
    $dealCoupons = DB::table('deal_coupons')->where('post_id', $deal->post_id)->get();
    return view('pages/back-end/forms/deal/coupon')->with('dealEdit', $deal)
                                                   ->with('dealCoupons', $dealCoupons);
}
```

I want to make my data look like :

```
   <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

But, I got like this:

```
   <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="123"> 
            <strong>123</strong>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tbody>
@foreach($dealCoupons->chunk(3) as $chunked_coupons)
    <tr>
        @foreach( $chunked_coupons as $dealCoupon )
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}">
                <strong>{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}</strong>
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach

`//setting counter`

`<?php $count = 0;?>`

```
@foreach($dealCoupons as $dealCoupon)

  //write for 1st counter
  @if($count == 0)
   <tr>
  @endif    
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="coupon" class="cekbox" value="{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}"> 
          <strong>{{$dealCoupon->CouponNo}}</strong>
      </td>

  //write for 3rd counter
  @if($count == 3)
      //reset counter
      <?php $count = 0;?>
  </tr>
  @else
    //add +1 to counter
    <?php $count++;?>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: please bare with code i wasnt able to fix the format here

Comment: Welcome :) @Miggy